# React: npm start works, npm run build throws ELIFECYCLE error (errno 1)

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, create-react-app, firebase-hosting

I have a React app (created using create-react-app).

`npm start` has initially worked and is still working.

When I ran `npm run build` initially a few days ago to deploy to Firebase hosting, it worked.
However, today, I noticed that while `npm start` still works, `npm run build` will throw the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fellon@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fellon@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The complete error log is:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v14.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle fellon@0.1.0~prebuild: fellon@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle fellon@0.1.0~build: fellon@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle fellon@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle fellon@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\edwar\Desktop\fellon\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\edwar\Downloads\cmder\bin;C:\Users\edwar\Downloads\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\Users\edwar\Downloads\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\Users\edwar\Downloads\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\php;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\php;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin;C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin;C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\share\vim\vim74;C:\Users\edwar\Downloads\cmder\
9 verbose lifecycle fellon@0.1.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\edwar\Desktop\fellon
10 silly lifecycle fellon@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle fellon@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle fellon@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: fellon@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid fellon@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\edwar\Desktop\fellon
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\edwar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.5.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error fellon@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the fellon@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I am using node: v14.5.0 / npm: 6.14.5 / react-scripts: 3.4.1 / webpack: 4.42.0

The code for this React app is: https://github.com/travelingaries/Fellon

Some of the approaches I've tried, but did not work, are:

1. `npm cache clean --force` => delete node_modules & package-lock.json => `npm install` => `npm run build`
2. `yarn build` instead of `npm run build`
3. Clone the entire project code => `npm install` in the new folder => `npm run start`
4. update node and npm versions, then try the above steps
5. make sure system32 is added in the PATH of environment variables (confirmed that it's already added)

I've been fiddling with this problem all day long, and I'm pretty much out of options.
It would mean a lot if someone can suggest a working solution to this problem.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I have tried your code there is a problem with the `public/index.html` file on `line 52` there is `<body">` instead of `<body>`

Comment: @MuhammadUsamaAshraf OMG this was it, erasing the " fixed the issue. Can't believe how much trouble that " caused.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in Muhammad Usama Ashraf's comment, it was a simple syntax error that went undetected in my case.
Changing <body"> to  fixed this issue.